# Como fazer uma caixa de busca com efeito hover?

Tags: html, css

Quando clica no icone de de pesquisa a caixa de busca abre.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.busca-organica{
 width:120px;
 height:27px;
 background-color:#FFF;
 display:none;
}

.btn-pesq{
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-pesq"><img src="img/lupa.png"></div>

<form action="busca.html" methode"GET">

 <input type"text" name="busca-organica" class="busca-organica"/>
 
</form>
```

Comment: É no *click* ou no *hover*?

Comment: @renan é quando clica no icone

Comment: Você tem algo pronto já?

Comment: @DiegoFelipe não eu queria saber como adicionar esse efeito !!

Comment: Então edite a pergunta e adicione o que você já fez, assim facilita a galera a te ajudar.

Comment: Tá vou colocar o código !

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Estou criando o código

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Já colei meu código na pergunta !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou deixar uma alternativa utilizando **jQuery** e **css**.

Suponhamos que você tenha um botão e um input em seu formulário. Vamos ocultar o input, e mostrar somente quando clicar no botão (lupa);

Para isso, utilizaremos a função [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) do jQuery, para termos o efeito desejado.

O código ficaria assim:

```js
( function() {
 $('#btn-search').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#search').animate({width: 'toggle'}).focus();

 });
} () );
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=fontawesome);

a[class*="fontawesome-"]:before,
span[class*="fontawesome-"]:before {
 display: block;
 font-family: 'FontAwesome', sans-serif;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

/* ---------- GENERAL ---------- */

body {
 background: #ccc;
 font: 87.5%/1.5em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 margin: 0;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: none;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner {
 border: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

fieldset {
 border: 0;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

input {
 border: 0;
 font-family: inherit;
 font-size: 100%;
 line-height: inherit;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

input:focus {
 outline: none;
}

input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

/* ---------- CLASSES ---------- */

.clearfix { *zoom: 1; }
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
 content: "";
 display: table; 
}
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }

.container {
 left: 50%;
 margin: -17px 0 0 -186px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 width: 372px;
}

/* ---------- TOOLBAR ---------- */

.toolbar {
 color: #fff;
}

.toolbar li {
 float: right;
}

.toolbar li:first-child a { border-radius: .5em 0 0 .5em; }
.toolbar li:last-child button { 
    border-radius: 0.5em 0 0 0.5em;
}

.toolbar a,
.toolbar input[type="search"],
.toolbar button {
 background: #3598db;
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
 padding: .5em 1em;
 position: relative;
}

.toolbar a:hover,
.toolbar input[type="search"]:hover,
.toolbar input[type="search"]:focus,
.toolbar button:hover {
 background: #2a80b9;
}

.toolbar input[type="search"] {
 display: none;
 height: 21px;
 width: 200px;
}

.toolbar input[type="search"]::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #fff; }
.toolbar input[type="search"]::-moz-placeholder { color: #fff; opacity: 1; }
.toolbar input[type="search"]:-moz-placeholder { color: #fff; opacity: 1; }
.toolbar input[type="search"]:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #fff; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <form action="javascript:void(0);" method="get">
   
   <fieldset>
    
    <ul class="toolbar clearfix">
     <li><input type="search" id="search" placeholder="O que você está buscando?"></li>
     <li><button type="submit" id="btn-search"><span class="fontawesome-search"></span></button></li>

    </ul>

   </fieldset>

  </form>

 </div> <!-- end container -->
```

Veja um [exemplo no JSFiddle aqui.](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/cbptx0L8/2/)

Fonte: [BootSnipp](http://bootsnipp.com/)

Outros exemplo você poderá encontrar [nesta resposta!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22610992/animation-search-bar-with-css)

Comment: valeu pela ajuda !! Era isso que eu queria.